# Histogram from a variable contains random number is not shown

Tags: netlogo

I want to plot a histogram that shows the distribution of the `cset-size` variable among the turtles. But when I specify the `histogram [cset-size] of turtles` for the histogram plot it does not show anything. Below I put the screenshot of my histogram setting and the entire code.

Is there something I forgot to specify or anything wrong with my code?

[image]

```
globals [ cset-size ]

to setup

  ca
  crt 100
  [
    set shape "person"
    set color yellow
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]

end

to go

  ask turtles
  [
    let a 4
    let b 1 / 6
    set cset-size round random-gamma a b
    set label cset-size
  ]

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems - the values to plot and the lack of time. The histogram construction itself is fine.

The first problem is that `cset-size` is in the `globals` list. That is, it is a global variable with only one value and each turtle is changing that value rather than storing their own. From your code, it is clear that you want each of your turtles to have its own value of `cset-size`. To have each turtle with its own value:

Delete `globals [ cset-size ]`

Try this instead: `turtles-own [ cset-size ]`

The second problem is that you don't have any concept of time in your model. By default, NetLogo updates plots each `tick`, so that it is not constantly updating the display and slowing down the model. This requires two changes:

- add the command `reset-ticks` as the last line in your setup procedure
- add the command `tick` as the last line in your go procedure

These will initialise the timer as part of the model setup, including telling NetLogo to display. And it will advance time each pass through the go procedure, which triggers the plots to update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215741/discussion-between-abdul-mubdi-bindar-and-jenb).